# Deltek Vision 7.6 - Column: does not exist when UpdateProject

Tags: sql, api, soap

I'm currently working in an integration with Deltek Vision 7.6, I'm using the SOAP API, it exposes all actions and I'm creating and updating records currently.

The problem is, adding a mew field in the database table and in Deltek Vision, executing the same call it returns an error like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DLTKVisionMessage>
   <ReturnCode>ErrSave</ReturnCode>
   <ReturnDesc>An unexpected error has occured while saving</ReturnDesc>
   <ChangesNotProcessed>
      <InsertErrors>
         <Error rowNum="1">
            <ErrorCode>InsertError</ErrorCode>
            <Message>Column: does not exist.</Message>
            <Table>Projects_MilestoneCompletionLog</Table>
            <ROW new="1" mod="1" del="0">
               <WBS1>100434</WBS1>
               <WBS2>1014</WBS2>
               <WBS3>SD</WBS3>
               <Seq>a0D0m000000cf9NEAQ</Seq>
               <CustMilestoneNumber>MS01</CustMilestoneNumber>
               <CustMilestoneName>DM91 - Data Maintenance SAQ</CustMilestoneName>
               <CustAmount>1150.0</CustAmount>
               <CustSiteTrackerDate>2018-07-06T10:01:50</CustSiteTrackerDate>
            </ROW>
         </Error>
      </InsertErrors>
   </ChangesNotProcessed>
   <Detail>Column: does not exist.</Detail>
   <CallStack>UpdateProject.SendDataToDeltekVision</CallStack>
</DLTKVisionMessage>
```

The problematic field is: CustSiteTrackerDate if I remove this from Vision and Database the update call happens correctly.

Does anyone knows if after create a new custom field in Deltek is anything special we need to do to allow the update calls throw the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been working with the Deltek Soap API as well and found this in some of the documentation:

> XML Schema for Vision Web Services/APIs The data that you are adding
>   or updating in the Vision database must be sent in XML format. The
>   format of the XML data must comply with the schema. The order of the
>   fields in your XML file must match the order of the fields that is
>   defined by the schema. If your XML file does not match the required
>   schema and the order of the fields, you will receive an error when you
>   use web services to update the Vision database. Each applicable Info
>   Center in Vision has an XML schema defined. Examples of the schema for
>   each Info Center are included in schema files that are located on the
>   Vision Web/app server in \Vision\Web\Xsd directory
>   ( is the directory where Deltek Vision is installed). The
>   names of the schema files start with the generic Info-Center-name
>   followed by ‘_Schema.xsd.’ For example, the name of the XML schema
>   file used for Employee Info Center would be ‘Employee_Schema.Xsd.’

It may be that you need to add the new field to the Info Center XML, go to the server hosting your Vision/Web/App and find the infocenter XML that this new field should exist in and make sure it is there.